# sts or ecilipse package explorer font size and sort right click options

Tags: java, css, eclipse, list

How to increase font size in Eclipse or STS package explorer without changing windows dpi settings?

How to write new rules for increase right click font size with in Eclipse or 
sort right click by alphabet order with in Eclipse?

Comment: i used the following code to inrease the font of package explorer

#org-eclipse-jdt-ui-PackageExplorer Tree,
#org-eclipse-ui-navigator-ProjectExplorer Tree {
  font-size: 10px; /* <-- Desired font size */
}

Answer (score 0):

```
#org-eclipse-jdt-ui-PackageExplorer Tree,
#org-eclipse-ui-navigator-ProjectExplorer Tree {
    font-size: 10px; /* <-- Desired font size */
}
```

check this file e4_default_win7.css
and add that code at the last of the file, restart ecilipse / sts

privide this works only if sts/ ecilipse are with your reach ie ur admin or if they ar not restricted